# How do I find out what android.R.layout xml files look like / get the source?

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to user the LayoutInfator to create a view. One of the options I'm thinking about is using the default android.R.layout files. However I'm finding it difficult to locate these files/how they look. It would be great if I could get some help in locating the source. I need to find the id's of the individual elements within those xml files.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They can be found in your Android SDK folder under:

/platforms/android-x/data/res/layout

Answer (score 5):

If you're interested in sources for SDK versions you don't have installed locally, you can browse them at the [Android on GitHub](http://android.github.io/) repositories:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/layout